# как задать %~dp10+ в bat файле?

Tags: cmd, bat

На данный момент могу задать только 1-9 входных файлов для обработки,

псевдокод:

```
@echo off
@color 0f

attrib -r "%~1"
.....
attrib -r "%~9"
pause
```

нужно получить больше этого значения (%~10+), желательно упростив через цикл, подскажите как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
@color 0f
:repeat
attrib -r "%~1"
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto repeat
pause
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает, все как надо.